# Is there an efficient algorithm to find all the maximum matching in any tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, matching-theory

A matching in a graph (G) is a set of mutually non-adjacent edges of (G). A maximum matching is a matching of maximal cardinality. A tree is an acyclic connected graph.

Is there an efficient algorithm to find all the maximum matching in any tree?

Comment: The number of maximal matchings of a tree can be exponential in the number of edges of that tree, so it isn't exactly clear what could be meant by "efficient algorithm".

Comment: Yes, you are right. At first, I would like to know if there are algorithms that can find all the maximum matchings in a tree (no brute force)

Comment: I think that if you look the null space of the adjacency matrix, you determine the subtrees that hold all the complexity of the problem

Comment: And in the Drazin inverse of the adjacency matrix you get at once all the edges which are in all the maximum matchings

Comment: And Drazin inverse actually tell more. It tell you which edges are never in a maximum matching and give full information about alternating path.